# GDB Cannot call function with string * parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, parameters, gdb, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer a binary by calling a few functions in GDB but I'm having trouble setting up the parameters.

When I do `print FUNCTION` I get,
`$2 = {std::string (std::string)} 0x564803a0b545 <FUNCTION(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)>`

In Ghidra, the function is listed as, `string *FUNCTION(string *__return_storage_ptr__,string *param2)`

I then set up the parameters like this,

```
set $param2 = (std::string *)malloc(sizeof(std::string))
call $param2->basic_string()
call $param2->assign("ASDASDASD")

set $param1 = (std::string *)malloc(sizeof(std::string))
call FUNCTION($param1, $param2)
```

But GDB says, `Cannot resolve function FUNCTION to any overloaded instance`

How should I set up my parameters? Thanks for the help!

Comment: $param1 is not constructed.

Comment: @S.M. Did you mean something like `call $param1->basic_string(); call $param1->assign("RandomText")`? Param one seems to be an out parameter, so I thought I should just give it a pointer. unfortunately adding these two calls did not work.